# Select last updated row ID and last deleted row ID in trigger before they occur in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to get the id of the updated row in a table to use it to update another table via trigger

Also need to get the id of the deleted row in a table to use it to update another table via trigger

How can I do this?

Is there any built in functions in SQL Server?

If not what kind of trick that can help to accomplish this

Comment: New and deleted rows are available inside of the triggers. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Remember that an update/insert/delete can affect multiple rows. You need to use the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo **tables**

Answer (score 5):

Within your trigger, if you want to know the OLD value that was either updated / deleted

```
SELECT idColumnName FROM deleted
```

Where  `idColumnName` is the column that contains the ID that you are interested in.

You can then use this ID value to then perform whatever processing that you need.
Additionally. if you want to use the NEW value being updated, the below query gives you that. This is useful especially in case of Updates where you want to compare old / new values of certain fields. In your case, since its an ID column, this will probably not be relevant

```
SELECT idColumnName FROM inserted
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer InSane, i just have remember the triggers tables inserted and updated actually i don't use the triggers quite often so i totally forgot about them.

Comment: JUst don;t assume there will only be one record. Write whateever code you have to processassuming the inserted and or deleted tables will conatin multiple rows. Assuming only one record is changed is the single biggest mistake in trigger writing.  Using a cursor to go through all the records is the next worst mistake, use a set-based process to deal with multiple rcords.